# Custom permalink structure with %postname% in front of domain name

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess, subdomains

We are running a software review website, and we have a very large amount of reviews currently done, and we would like to restructure if its at all possible.

I would like to know if there's a chance of getting some sort of a redirect, or custom permalink structure to point as following:

- The current permalink structure for the website is:

  - `domainname.com`/%category%/%postname%
- And the required/desired outcome would be:

  - %postname%`.domainname.com`/%category%

So basically point each single post, to a custom permalink, that will show the post title in front of the domain name, and if that post has a category set, it should show it after the domain name.

Other thing worth mentioning is that the website is running wordpress 4.1.1, in single site, not multi site/network.

After reading through the codex, it seems like a multisite wordpress install may be worth a shot, however, I'm not sure if this is the case, as we only want the postname to show in front of the domain name, and this may be better suited to a category approach website.

Any tips or advice are most welcomed,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a multi site approach wouldn't work since you will be creating multiple blogs, each will work as an individual WP installation, so each of them will hold multiple posts, pages, categories, etc that are not shared between blogs.

The url you are proposing can't be defined using wordpress routing, so a custom code will need to be developed for this approach.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it even *possible* to have the same (single site, non network installation, for sake of argument) WordPress site running from two or more subdomains? Don't the `siteurl` and `home` entries in wp_options (aka WordPress address / Site address in Settings > General) always need to be fully qualified?

Comment: Yes, you are right, WP will always check if the siteurl is correct, if not it will redirect, that is why this can't be done with WP default router, so custom code to hack the default router is needed to handle this type of url.

Comment: I was afraid of that, maybe instead of making a custom code to hack the default router, we will move to a multisite network, and change the original idea, instead of using %postnam%.domain.com we will simulate %category%.domain.com/%postname%/ , basically making a subdomain for each of our category, and work our way from there. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Glad it helped you. @Crispy-George Just as a favor, can you accept the answer :) it will help my score.

Comment: For sure, I'm going to wait until tomorrow, see if anyone has a different opinion, and if nothing happens, I will check yours